# What is the gradient mask equivalent in Flash CC for HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, flash, canvas

I used to create a gradient mask in Flash using these three lines of AS3 while having two movieclips on the stage, one of which had a gradient block in it:

```
gradientMask_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
something_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
something_mc.mask = gradientMask_mc;
```

Now that I'm experimenting with Flash CC's HTML5 Canvas, I can't seem to find the equivalent. Is it an entirely different setup or what? My searches yield only the AS3 solutions. Please and thanks!

Comment: Hi Tessa, did you find a solution for this in  CC animate?

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML5 canvas and javascript to blend two images with a gradient.

```
// img1, img2 are the two images 
// ctx is the canvas.


// setup. Only do this once or when you change the masking
// create a mask canvas the size of the first image
var gradImg1Masked = document.createElement("canvas");
gradImg1Masked.width = img1.width;  // set the width and height
gradImg1Masked.height = img1.height;

var ctx1 = gradImg1Masked.getContext("2d",{ alpha: true }); // get the context

var gradient = ctx1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, img1.height); // create a gradient
                                                                // assuming its from 
                                                                // top to bottom.

// add colour stops black full opaque at top to full transparent at bottom
gradient.addColorStop( 0, "rgba(0,0,0,1)" );
gradient.addColorStop( 1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)" );   

ctx1.globalAlpha = 1;  // ensure alpha is on full
ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // ensure correct filter   
ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);  // draw the image on the mask canvas

ctx1.fillStyle = gradient;   // set the fill style
ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"; // set filter to mask letting
                                               // only opaque pixels in   
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, img1.width, img1.height); // create the masked image
                                              // by rendering the gradiant ontop

// gradImg1Masked is now the masked copy of img1
```

That was the setup. Below is the rendering.

```
// Rendering the images with the mask
// simply draw the second image and the the first on top
// ctx is the render surface you are displaying
// x and y are where you want the top left of the images to be.
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;  // ensure alpha is on full
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // ensure correct filter   

// draw the second image at x,y screen pos
ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0,img2.width,img2.height,x,y,img2.width,img2.height);

// draw the masked image ontop using the second image's size
ctx.drawImage( gradImg1Masked, 
       0, 0, gradImg1Masked.width, gradImg1Masked.height,
       x, y, img2.width, img2.height);
```

Hope this helps. There may be an easier way Flash CC's HTML5 Canvas but I find frameworks provide little benefit over the very functional HTML5/Javascript while obfuscating what is happening and also slowing everything down. Their use is of course a personal decision.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try this out!

Comment: Thanks.. Lucky I saw your message as I just noticed an error in my code. Setting the gradient stops I added two at 0, now it is correct.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Turns out that particular project got delayed because another became a higher priority, so I haven't had the chance to come back to it anyway. But as soon as I get back to it, I'll definitely let you know what happens.